# Maximum call stack size exceeded error in a recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, recursion, browser

I received a max call stack size exceeded error on the following code, (I intend to run the recursive loop till infinity). Is this method at all possible or is there a logical fallacy?

```
const example = ['hello.', 'hi there.'];

        textSequence(0);
        
        function textSequence(i) {

            if (example.length > i) {
                $('#welcome').fadeIn(1500);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('welcome').fadeOut(2500);
                },4000);
                $('#welcome').text(example[i]);
                textSequence(++i);
            } 
            else if (example.length == i) {
                textSequence(0);
            }

        }
```

Comment: `i==0`. You loop once. Then `i==1`, you loop twice. Then `i==2`, third loop. Now `example.length == i`, so you start all over again, back to 0,1,2, then 0,1,2, then 0,1,2... infinite loop indeed. The function calls itself infinitely many times, so you reach a max call stack failsafe.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `else if (example.length == i) {` ?  You are just starting everything over from scratch ..  Moving from 1 if to another ..  infinitely ..

Comment: Jeremy, so can I use infinite loops to create a looping text animation? If not, can you suggest me some other ways of doing so?

Comment: _"I intend to run the recursive loop till infinity"_ a function executed on an interval would probably serve you better, eg [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) / [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) / [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Patrick thanks, I am just starrting out on JS and I didnt use the setInterval() before, now  I know how stupid my problem is

Comment: But `fadeIn` is asynchronous. It takes time (1500ms in this case), but does not block the event loop. The code keeps running while the animation is being performed. You are expecting the code to wait until the animation finishes, but it does not.